# React Draw Image on Canvas

Tags: reactjs, next.js, html5-canvas, gsap

I wanted to do a GSAP animation sequence by drawing it into a canvas with Next.js Typescript. When I try to draw on the canvas with Next.js, their [Image API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) returns the following object instead of an [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) (note that nextjs doesn't allow to use the standart image API saying it's undefined otherwise):

```
{
   $$typeof: Symbol(react.element),
   key: null,
   props: {style: {…}, children: Array(4)},
   ref: null,
   type: "span",
   _owner: FiberNode {tag: 0, key: '99462441', stateNode: null, elementType: ƒ, type: ƒ, …},
   _store: {validated: false},
   _self: null,
   _source: null,
   [[Prototype]]: Object
}
```

This results in the canvas context [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

`context.drawImage(images[0], 0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height)`,

to return an error be it wasn't an the expecetd type

This is the abbreviated version of the code I'm using to try and render the images:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { gsap } from "gsap/dist/gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";
import Image from "next/image";


const AnimationSection = () => {

    const images = [] // array to import the images
    const canvasRef = useRef(null); // canvas reference
    let context = null; // canvas context

    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    const videoFrames = { frame: 0 };

    const framesCount = 111

    // Import of images
    for (let index = 0; index < framesCount; index++) {
        const image = require(`../../public/frontpagehero/frame${index}.jpg`)
        const imageHTMLElement = Image(image.default) // can't use new Image()
        images.push(imageHTMLElement)
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        if(canvasRef.current) {
            context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
            context.drawImage(images[0], 0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height);
        }

        gsap.to(videoFrames, {
          frame: framesCount - 1,
          duration: 1,
          snap: "frame",
          ease: "none",
          scrollTrigger: {
            scrub: 0.5
          },
          onUpdate: render // use animation onUpdate instead of scrollTrigger's onUpdate
      })


      function render() {
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height);
          context.drawImage(images[videoFrames.frame], 0, 0);
        }

    }, []);

    return (
      <div>
        <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
      </div>
    );
};

export default AnimationSection;
```

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use `next/image`? You'd probably not want to use it for this scenario.

Comment: I don't want to use it but Next.js forces me to use it. If I'm not importing it, it says that `new Image()` is undefined.